# How to insert just year and month into date field?

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `table_date` which currently I am using `now()` to insert the current date (`2011-02-23`). I know I can manipulate this with sql/php to show me year and monthname. However, I want to know if it's possible to just insert into `table_date` the current date as year-month like this `2011-02`? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `DATE` field is always going to be a full date, and as far as I know, it is also always required to specify a full date.

It might be easiest to use `01`, like `2011-02-01` for February 2011.

Obviously, you can format the output of a `DATE` field to your liking when querying it:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fieldname,"%Y-%m");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you insert something like `2010-10` into a `DATE` column, mysql throws a warning and inserts `0000-00-00`. If you do not want to specify a certain day, you can insert something like `2010-10-00`. Pay attention when querying for "all entries in October 2010" since `WHERE date >= '2010-10-01'` will not return `2010-10-00`.