# Mysql wont accept incomplete date

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to insert an incomplete date into a mysql table with a column of type `date` called `video_date` with the following query

```
UPDATE videos SET video_date = '1961-00-00' WHERE video_id = 6
```

However the date just gets set to 0000-00-00. When I try typing the above query into the SQL query window in PHPmyadmin it gives me the following error "Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'video_date' at row 1" and the date in the column remains as 0000-00-00.

I cant figure out what the problem is because according to these stackoverflow threads it should be possible to insert incomplete dates, such as '1961-00-00' or '1961-05-00':

[Store incomplete date in MySQL date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882788/store-incomplete-date-in-mysql-date-field)

[How to insert just year and month into date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091131/how-to-insert-just-year-and-month-into-date-field)

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT added quotes around the date but the same problem persists.

Comment: it is an incorrect date, because it doesn't exist, make a varchar out of it and live with converting it, or simple update a normal date

Comment: It's not even a date expression but an arithmetic expression resulting in `1961`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @stickybit  I tried `UPDATE videos SET video_date = '1961-00-00' WHERE video_id = 6` and also tried using other delimiters such as @ as per the linked Mysql documentation in the top answer, but I still get the same problem when running the above query in PHP myadmin. @nbk did you look at the threads I linked which explicitly state that Mysql should permit dates of formats such as '2014-00-00'?

Comment: *Structured* Query Language. This implies that data storage is strict. The acceptance of `0000-00-00` was a mistake that is being slowly deprecated. If you want incomplete month, incomplete day of month, I'd suggest putting those as BOOLEAN fields and have the date have` 01` for those. Handle the representation to the user when you retrieve those fields.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to your mysql_mode set with the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES which includes the mode NO_ZERO_IN_DATE.

[Strict SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)